# Create GeometryModel3D object from list of Vector3D in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, 3d

I'm trying to build a 3D model (`ModelVisual3D`) out of a `List<Vector3D>` generated from the GCode-Parser. I did use this JavaScript code as base for my C# version of it.

**JavaScript Code:**
https://github.com/hudbrog/gCodeViewer/blob/master/js/renderer3d.js

```
var buildModelIteration = function(layerNum){
    var j;
    var cmds  = model[layerNum];
    if(!cmds)return;
    for(j=0;j<cmds.length;j++){
        if(!cmds[j])continue;
        if(isNaN(cmds[j].x))cmds[j].x=prevX;
        if(isNaN(cmds[j].y))cmds[j].y=prevY;
        if(isNaN(cmds[j].z))cmds[j].z=prevZ;
        if(!cmds[j].extrude){
        }
        else {
            geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(prevX, prevY, prevZ));
            geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(cmds[j].x, cmds[j].y, cmds[j].z));
        }
        prevX = cmds[j].x;
        prevY = cmds[j].y;
        prevZ = cmds[j].z;
    }
};

var buildModelIteratively = function(){
    var i;

    for(i=0;i<model.length;i+=1){
        buildModelIteration(i);
        //TODO: need to remove UI stuff from here

    }
    var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: renderOptions["colorLine"], lineWidth: 2, opacity: 0.6, fog: false});
    geometry.computeBoundingBox();
    object.add(new THREE.Line(geometry, lineMaterial, THREE.LinePieces));
    var center = new THREE.Vector3().add(geometry.boundingBox.min, geometry.boundingBox.max).divideScalar(2);
    object.position = center.multiplyScalar(-1);

}
```

Out of the function above, I get a list of Vector3D objects. From this, I'm trying to greate a ModelVisual3D object.

```
ModelVisual3D mod = new ModelVisual3D();
        GeometryModel3D geometry = new GeometryModel3D();
        MeshGeometry3D meshGeometry = new MeshGeometry3D();

        foreach (Vector3D vect in listOfVectors)
        {
            meshGeometry.Positions.Add(new Point3D(vect.X, vect.Y, vect.Z));

            //meshGeometry.TriangleIndices.Add(cnt)
        }
        meshGeometry.CalculateNormals();

        meshGeometry.Validate();
        geometry.Geometry = meshGeometry;
        geometry.Transform = new TranslateTransform3D(2,0,-1);
        geometry.Material = new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.White);
        mod.Content = geometry;
```

I guess I need to add some `Triangles` as well, however I'm not familiar with 3D Models.

**Edit1:**
What I want to achive is, to get the bounding box of my points cloud and add a surface to it.

Like `THREE.computeBoundingBox()`, see example below:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    geometry.vertices.push(
        new THREE.Vector3( -10,  10, 0 ),
        new THREE.Vector3( -10, -10, 0 ),
        new THREE.Vector3(  10, -10, 0 )
    );

geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );

geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
```

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Geometry.computeBoundingBox

Any help is appreciated.

If further information are needed, just let me know.

Comment: Please add some more details. What kind of model is this? Where do you expect a surface and why? Post screenshots if they help with the explanation. Your first method already creates `THREE.Line`, which you can just add to the scene. However, for most variables, it is unclear what they are and where they come from (`geometry`, `object`, `cmds`)

Comment: I actually just want the bounding box of my points/vectors. It seems pretty easy with the THREE library, however I don‘t get it done in C#. Geometry = 3D object / cmds is the Gcode command where I got x,y,z out of it. You find the whole code at the github url posted in the OP. Thanks!